# How to Convert Rows to Columns in Oracle using pivot

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the table

```
id  year        quarter     total
1   2016        1           100
1   2016        2           200
1   2016        3           300
1   2016        4           400
2   2016        1           100
2   2016        2           200
```

I want to get the output:

```
id  year    total1  total2  total3  total4
1   2016    100     200     300     400
2   2016    100     200
```

I have tried

```
SELECT year,
       "1"     AS total1,
       "2"     AS total2,
       "3"     AS total3,
       "4"     AS total4
  FROM (SELECT 
               *
          FROM mytable 
               PIVOT (... FOR quarter IN (1, 2, 3, 4))
         where year=2016) a

;
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment that requires the use of the `PIVOT` operator? It's not the way I'd go (I'd use conditional aggregation like the posted answers), but if you have to use `PIVOT`, you have to use `PIVOT`.

Comment: Sorry, I do not want max or sum any values. I simply want to output the value of total in every quarter as a new column

Comment: You're not understanding how the code works. Try it out before you dismiss it.

Comment: Your query [works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c5c4bd2228dd1221722681b8394d33b6) if you use `max(total)` or `sum(total)` instead of dots. Pivot needs aggregation, but in this case it will create rows for each `id`. The question is what to do if there are two rows for same quarter with same ID. You want sum, max or separate rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do aggregation :

```
SELECT id, year,
       SUM(CASE WHEN quarter = 1 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS total1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN quarter = 2 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS total2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN quarter = 3 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS total3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN quarter = 4 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS total4
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY id, year;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking for the usage of pivot() function, please try below:

```
    SELECT id,
           year,
           "1_TOTAL" AS total1,
           "2_TOTAL" AS total2,
           "3_TOTAL" AS total3,
           "4_TOTAL" AS total4
      FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable) PIVOT (SUM (total) AS total
                               FOR (quarter)
                               IN (1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Note: The question doesn't specify whether you're looking for a sum() or max(). For the desired output that you gave, you may use either sum() or max()